# How to refactor a filter on the Rows sent to a DataGridView using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

**Is there an easier way to filter rows in the DataGridView of this way ?
beacuse it Looks a little complex
**

```
    private void Reread()
    {
        string nameFilter = txtSearch.Text;
        string addressFilter = comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0 ? comboBox1.Text : "";
        string depFilter = comboBox2.SelectedIndex > 0 ? comboBox2.Text : "";
        DateTime? birthdate = chkBirthdate.Checked ? dateTimePicker1.Value.Date : (DateTime?) null;
        DateTime? fromDate = chkRange.Checked ? dateTimePicker2.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null;
        DateTime? toDate = chkRange.Checked ? dateTimePicker3.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null;

        using (DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext())
        {
            var result = from p in db.Persons
                         where
                            (nameFilter.Length > 0 && p.FullName.Contains(nameFilter) || nameFilter.Length == 0)
                         && (addressFilter.Length > 0 && p.Address == addressFilter || addressFilter.Length == 0)
                         && (depFilter.Length > 0 && p.Department == depFilter || depFilter.Length == 0)
                         && (birthdate == null || (birthdate != null && p.Birthdate == birthdate))
                         && ((fromDate == null || toDate == null) || (fromDate != null && toDate != null && p.Birthdate >= fromDate && p.Birthdate <= toDate))

                         select p;

            var resultData = result.ToList();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = resultData;
        }
```

Comment: This looks like you are doing filtering on LINQ result set, you are not doing any filtering on `DataGridView`. What are you trying to ask ?

Comment: question @Ahmed why not create a query or stored procedure to get the data returned that you are looking for and bind it to the DataGridView, then from there you can still filter and rebind the data using `DataSet.DataTable.Filter()` method

Comment: Simplicity aside, the flexible UI has a large number of permutations of filters - and generating the predicates in the form of `column = @filter OR column IS NULL` will create terrible query plans in Sql. I would suggest building the [IQueryable dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764080/creating-a-dynamic-query-using-iqueryable), or using [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/), such that only the applicable predicates are applied.

Comment: for example if you wanted to filter `dataGridView1` you could do the following 
`(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text);` or you cold create an Instance of `BindingSource` like this `Also works BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource; bs.Filter =your filter or like expression`

Comment: My brother @Habib this method help me to Multi filtering the DGV using a TextBox  , 2 CombBoxes and 3 DateTimePickerd (cumulative filtering)
i look for another simple way th do this

Comment: My broter @MethodMan , actualy i make the datasource of this DGV is a SP in Form_Load Event .but i want to do this using LINQ

Comment: My brother @StuartLC , i can't understand your idea 
can you give more explain  ??

Comment: @Ahmed I've provided some ideas. Can you think of a more specific question / title for your question, as this could be interpreted to be a code review type question in its current format.

Answer (score 0):

Questions asking for improvements to working code (`easier`) are better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com as they imply a degree of opinion. I believe are some design improvements needed in your code, and the current form of the optional Linq predicates will result in Sql Queries which exhibit poor performance when there are a large number of rows in the Persons table.

- Separate the concerns of parsing the user input (filters for the query) from the act of actually querying the data. Generally, this would be split into different classes, and even different assemblies, representing these different tiers / concerns (e.g. presentation tier and data / repository tier)
- Introduce validation before hitting the database. A query with no filters will attempt to retrieve all Person rows, waste IO and potentially crash your application with an `OutOfMemoryException`. Also, you could separate validation into a separate method or class.
- As per my comment, the 'optional' predicate filter pattern results in Sql along the lines of  `@filter <> null AND column = @filter OR @filter IS NULL` which will result in poor Sql Query performance and will cache plans which aren't suited to other permutations of filter. What you want to be doing here is omitting any unwanted predicates entirely (i.e. where the user has left a filter empty). I've used a simple composition of `IQueryable` below to do this, but for more advanced cases, you'll want to turn to `PredicateBuilder` or `DynamicLinq` to achieve more complex predicates.

```
IList<Person> FindPersons(string nameFilter, string addressFilter, 
                          DateTime? birthdate, .. etc)
{
   using (var db = new DbDataContext())
   {
     var query = db.Persons.AsQueryable();
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(nameFilter))
     {
        query = query.Where(p => p.FullName.Contains(nameFilter));
     }
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(addressFilter))
     {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Address == addressFilter);
     }
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(depFilter))
     {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Department == depFilter);
     }
     if (birthdate.HasValue)
     {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Birthdate == birthdate);
     }
     query = query.Take(1000); // Sanity, limit the rows

     return query.ToList();
   }
}

protected void OnSearchPersonClick()
{
    // Parsing
    var nameFilter = txtSearch.Text;
    var addressFilter = comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0 ? comboBox1.Text : "";
    DateTime? birthdate = chkBirthdate.Checked 
           ? dateTimePicker1.Value.Date 
           : (DateTime?) null;       
    // etc

    // Validation
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(nameFilter) 
        && string.IsNullOrWhitespace(addressFilter) 
        && !(birthdate.HasValue)) // etc
    {
        ShowErrorMessageToUser("Please provide at least one filter");
        return;
    }

    // Bind
    dataGridView1.DataSource = FindPersons();
}
```

Comment: Thanx my brother @StuartLC , i'm sorry for my bad english language
i'll try this

Comment: the filtering not work well , i'll set to u my exampel
https://www.dropbox.com/s/elbpvx59zvdr20u/LINQ%20Filter.zip?dl=0